Molten Metal Blobs moving and fusing on a surface?
I am trying to re-create an advert as a practise which involves molten metal fluid blobs moving along a surface and fusing with other blobs in a natural way.
Here is the video - 3 scenes are involved : https://youtu.be/VcZetwcBZ6Q?si=7BZDPJKi1ds6BVdp
I have tried all sorts of methods involving the inbuilt Blender fluid sim, metaballs and geometry nodes and particles systems and have gone back to a geometry nodes method where I basically use blobs on a path making up one cube object but deforming with the displace modifier (to create the blob wobble). I then have a remesh modifier in the modifier stack to create the merging effect of molten metal particles as the blobs get close.
The problem comes when I animate as I have each blob on a path keyframed in geometry nodes but trying to then get each blob to move at the right speed and position relative to one another in a way which creates the effect of molten metal moving is almost impossible. It just looks like blobs moving independently.
There doesn't seem to be a workable solution to use a plug-in to animate the number and position of blobs - flip fluids won't do it, nor other plug-ins for blender. There is one called 'realflow' which I could import as alembic files but I don't know how to use that software and I am not sure if I can use the free version (the paid version is expensive)
I am just canvassing opinion on if anyone has ever done this as I think there are not any tutorials on how to do this online. If anyone can help me reach a solution I would be happy to give back and post a tutorial on how these scenes can be done.

If I were to attempt this effect, I would use a particle system with metaballs as the particle to get the merging effect. As for getting the particles to behave as you want, I would try changing the physics of the particles from Newtonian to Boids. That way you can make them move on a surface. Boid particles can be made to flock to an object, maintain a certain distance from each other, etc. With some fiddling, I am sure you can come up with settings for the desired movement.
Here is a video on the boid system you might find useful  and a video on using metaballs as particles . Good luck. I hope you found this helpful.

Thanks for the posts. This is not a regular forum, according to site rules links to answers are not answers if the link goes missing your answer becomes an empty shell without content. Answers should be substantial and stand on their own without relying on external data like links, videos or images. Instead of having users go through external links, either transcribe essential parts of the process here, linking the source, or posts these in the comments section instead.
